# Display text inside bar in bar chart with Chartist.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chartist.js

So, I'm trying to display some text inside the actual bars of a bar chart using Chartist.js charts. The end result should look something like this:

[image]

Which property do I need to set in order to get the text inside the bars?

Comment: please provide your code. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [chartist-bar-labels](https://github.com/YorkshireInteractive/chartist-bar-labels) it should provide what you are looking for, with it you can add the following code:

```
Chartist.plugins.ctBarLabels({
      position: {
        x: function (data) {
          return data.x1 + 50
        }
      },
      labelOffset: {
        y: 7
      },
      labelInterpolationFnc: function (text) { //<--- this adds text to your bards
        return text + '%' 
      }
    })
```