# How to add text in bar graph not middle in graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, chartist.js

We are using chartist js to make graph chart, but i can not find any solution to how to add text after bar grid.

Please see the below image to clear the pitcher:-

[image]

`Jquery` setting :-

```
new Chartist.Bar('#ct-campaignsBy', {
            labels: ['Campaigns 1', 'Campaigns 2', 'Campaigns 3' ],
            series: [
                [5, 4, 3 ]
            ]
        }, {
            seriesBarDistance: 10,
            reverseData: false,
            horizontalBars: true,
            axisY: {
                offset: 80
            }
        });
```

Comment: This might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348622/display-text-inside-bar-in-bar-chart-with-chartist-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display text inside bar in bar chart with Chartist.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348622/display-text-inside-bar-in-bar-chart-with-chartist-js)

Comment: i try this but text margin form left side is same for all, i want when bar end then the text come, bar is small and large both size.